# Setting Value in KeyValuePair to a default value

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, keyvaluepair

I'm working on something where i need to get some values from database and into a `DataTable. 
I have this a`KeyValuePair` list declared

```
  List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> thisList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
```

The key for `thisList` is looped from 1 to 31 (Thats actually days), while the Value is set to 0 by default by the loop below. (In reality value is a count of something)

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                thisList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, 0));
            }
```

Somewhere else i am using this list to store values for rows in a `DataTable`.

While this is working properly for the first row in a DataTable, when one row is added, the value in the `thisList` is aggregated instead of replaced. I use this loop here for that:

```
DataTable table;
//columns set somewhere here... not the issue in focus
foreach(var value in aBigListOfThings)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < thisList.Count(); i++)
   {

      if (condition)
         {
                int sumtemp = 0;
                int.TryParse(someVariable.FirstOrDefault().someValue, out temp);
                temp += thisList[i].Value;
                // ====Possibly the issue  
                thisList[i] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(unrelatedValue, sumtemp);                            
                //=====                                                                         
           }
    }

   //====  attempt the reset the value in the keyvaluepair to 0


 if (someothercondition) 
    {
         for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
         {
               thisList[i] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, 0);
         }
    }
}
```

Before i added the fix to reset the value to 0 (`if (someothercondition)`), the data looked like this:

```
1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | ...... 31 <---key
------------------------------
2  | 4  | 6  | 8  | 10 | ...... n  <---value
3  | 7  | 11 | 15 | 19 | ...... n  <---value
```

While it's supposed to look like this

```
1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | ...... 31 <---key
------------------------------
2  | 4  | 6  | 8  | 10 | ...... n <---value
1  | 3  | 5  | 7  | 9  | ...... n <---value
```

To my understanding and looking around for solutions, `KeyValuePair` is immutable and if anything it cannot be added (like in `+=` , but can be replaced.. (please correct me if i'm wrong)

When i used the fix (wayyyy above), i get an index out of range exception.  `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index` Which i take to mean that `thisList[i] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, 0);` is adding more to the list instead of replacing the existing ones..

... If you are still reading through this.. My question is
a) Why is `KeyValuePair` said to be immutable when its aggregating the values?
b) How can i simply replace the value in the `keyvaluepair` to be 0 without? Or is it possible?

ANY help would be really useful at this point.. Been wrecking my head for a while. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting index of `List<T>` is 0, not 1. That means your last loop needs to look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
{
    thisList[i] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, 0);
}
```

This will replace the 31 `KeyValuePair`s in indexes 0 through 30.

By the way, why didn't you create the loop in the same way as the previous one, which is working?

Comment: Totally overlooked this! Also the culprit of the index out or range exception!  Thank you! :) It works now

Comment: @Tsar another way instead change `thisList[i].Value;` to `thisList[i+1].Value;`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just get it and set the value? eg.

```
Dictionary<string, int> list = new Dictionary<string, int>();
list["test"] = 1;
list["test"] += 1;
Console.WriteLine (list["test"]); // will print 2
```